# What are the steps for finding consumer surplus based on x bar and the demand equation?

Tags: calculus

The demand equation for a certain product is $p = 1000 - 0.1x - 0.01x^2$. Find the consumers surplus if $\bar{x} = 200$.

I was unfortunate enough to miss the class that dealt with consumer surplus & demand, so I'm wondering if someone can explain what steps I need to go through to work this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The price $p$ when $200$ units are sold is, by the given formula, $1000-(0.1)(200)-(0.01)(200^2)$. Call this number $P$.

There would have been people willing to pay more than $P$. These people got a "deal," For the $\Delta x$ people willing to pay between $p(x)$ and $p(x+\Delta x)$, the amount "saved" is approximately $(p(x)-P)\Delta x$. "Add up" (integrate) from $x=0$ to $x=200$. The amount collectively saved (the consumer surplus) is
$$\int_0^{200} (p(x)-P)\,dx.$$
For our particular problem, use the given function $p(x)$, and the value $P$ that we calculated.   The integration will be straightforward.

**Remark:** Anyone  unfortunate enough to have taught a calculus course in which this notion of marginal importance in economics is  covered knows how to solve the problem. The notion of consumer surplus comes up not because it is significant, but because it is an "application" of the integral.

Comment: Thank you Andre, you've made it very simple to understand this question. Superb explanation! Also, thanks for mentioning that this example is used solely because it is an application of the integral.